# iOS Calendar Adding Its Own Alerts

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar

I am using a Google account on latest iOS, and the Calendar app appears to be adding it's own alerts to all-day events:

[image: example of ios bug]
<sup>Click to enlarge images</sup>
Yes, I checked the "default alerts" in Settings:

[image: default alerts]
<sup>Click to enlarge images</sup>
And even confirmed Google Calendar doesn't have the alerts:

[image: google calendar]
<sup>Click to enlarge images</sup>
So... what gives? I've also tried deleting the entire Google account from my iPhone and re-adding it. No joy. It's driving me bonkers. Perhaps it's a bug with iOS 9.0.2, or something I'm just not understanding. Is anyone else having this issue/know a fix?

Comment: Are there any other apps that sync with your Google Calendar? Maybe some other app is fetching events, adding alert to them and syncing back too Google.

Comment: @Behdad if it's something like that, I would expect the changes to be getting sync'd back to my Google Calendar. They're not. They only are showing up on my iPhone under the native calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use **Apple Calendar** on your Mac? (Preferences -> Alerts). Perhaps these are the preferences that push those alerts to your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and my conclusion is that it's the macOS Calendar that syncs wrong data to iCloud, when adding **daily events** in an **iCloud** **shared** calendar (the calendar belongs to my wife's iCloud, shared to my iCloud account)

- macOS Calendar shows correctly created events, **no alarms**
- My wife's iCloud sync to iPhone/iPad shows correct events, **no alarms**
- My own iCloud sync to iPhone/iPad shows the events **WITH alarms**...
- My own iCloud web shows the events **WITH alarms**

It used to be fixable by removing iCloud calendar from iPhone/iPad, but today it consistently syncs the events back WITH alarms - on both devices
Ignoring the Calendar settings for default alarms completely (but only on my iCloud account - not my wife's/the owner of the iCloud calendar)

It appears macOS Calendar syncs shared daily events WITH unconfigured alarms, ignoring the macOS Calendar alarm settings (no alarms on daily events) - this was a problem on macOS 10.13 and 10.14.

Answer (score -1):

On the IOS calendar it is sometimes able to schedule things on its own. If you have scheduled something in previous years it may ask you if you are doing that thing again. For the Google Calendar I don’t use them so I don’t know much about that.